# Spring Security Limiting URL access by roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement SpringSecurity mechanism on this little project, that will limit interactions with the URL of the request by roles.

I have two roles **USER** and **ADMIN**, **USER** can see the items, but not add or delete them, while **ADMIN** can do both.

Now the problem, the requests from **USER** role and even unauthenticated users to create/delete/read an item are allowed somehow. It seems to me that my application is not configured correctly somewhere.

SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}12345").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}12345").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("api/items", "api/items/").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @GetMapping("/api/items")
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return itemService.getAllItems();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/addItem",consumes = {"application/json"},produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public Item addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
        itemService.addItem(item);
        return item;
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "api/deleteItem/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String deleteItem(@PathVariable int id) {
        itemService.deleteItem(id);
        return "Deleted";
    }
}
```

I am sending requests to the following URL's:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/items        // GET
http://localhost:8080/api/addItem      // POST
http://localhost:8080/api/deleteItem/4 // DELETE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding slashes to your antmatcher patterns, such as:

```
antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

The Spring documentation mentions:

> Note: a pattern and a path must both be absolute or must both be relative in order for the two to match. Therefore it is recommended that users of this implementation to sanitize patterns in order to prefix them with "/" as it makes sense in the context in which they're used.

Furthermore, Spring security uses the first match of all the matching rules expressed. I would recommend reordering the matchers from most-specific to less-specific as otherwise a call to `api/items` will be matched by the `api/**` matcher instead of being matched by the `api/items` matcher.

```
.antMatchers("/api/items", "api/items/").hasRole("USER")
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have tried        `antMatchers("/api/items", "api/items/", "/api/items/", "api/items").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`, which unfortunately didn't help, if I use noauth method in Postman it will allow its execution

Comment: @dur please correct me if I am wrong, shouldn't this line allow only authenticated requests`.anyRequest().authenticated()`?

Comment: @Hatik: Yes, if you use `.anyRequest().authenticated()` all URLs have to be authenticated.

Comment: @dur I finally managed to understand the problem which allowed users with no authentication to access some level of functionality. Postman saves cookies from the last request, that is why they appeared authenticated. Maybe the whole problem also because of that, will try it out

Answer (score 1):

On top of `@GetMapping` or `@PostMapping` you can add following annotation to manage Role based access

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping(value = "/api/addItem",consumes = {"application/json"},produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public Item addItem(@RequestBody Item item) {
    itemService.addItem(item);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: it gives me 403 Forbidden response, when I am almost sure my credentials are ok, and sometimes after restarting the app 401 Unauthorized...